# pdflatex + Babel + Arabic & Hebrew

Tags: babel, arabic, hebrew

I'm trying to use Babel for Arabic & Hebrew (both as secondary to English) in pdflatex. I had it working for just Arabic with

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,hebrew,english]{babel}   

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\AR{أهلاً}
%\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{שלום}
\end{document}
```

But I can't figure out how to extend this for Hebrew. As soon as I try to add Hebrew (uncomment the line above), it gives me an encoding error on the Hebrew. If I switch to utf8x, it gives me an encoding error on the Arabic.

As suggested, I've tried switching to xelatex and polyglossia. This can display Arabic and Hebrew, however when I add in the style file I need with hyperref, it breaks. Here's that minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[hyperref]{sty_file}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
%\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

%\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Noto Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]

\title{Hebrew Arabic Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

English

%\begin{Arabic}
%أهلاً
%\end{Arabic}

%\begin{hebrew}
%שלום
%\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

As soon as you uncomment the first commented lines, it breaks my styling. It would be a lot to paste the style file here, but it is included in this [overleaf document](https://www.overleaf.com/read/jjcgdhxphbfp).

Any ideas? I've tried everything else I found on this stack exchange with no luck. :/ Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Posting code is just what we're looking for in a question. You're almost there, just complete your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The easier it is to copy and test your code, the more likely your question will be answered and can help others in a similar situation.

Comment: There are posts on this site about getting Hebrew to work with `pdflatex`, but in my view it's just not work the pain unless you really have to. If at all possible switch to `xelatex`. You can even use `babel` now if your requirements are not too complex.

Comment: @thymaro, sorry about that! Thanks for the reminder. I modified to include a minimal working example where it works and what breaks it.

Comment: @DavidPurton, when I switch to xelatex, it compiles but neither the Arabic nor the Hebrew display in the PDF, it's just blank. Is there more I need to add for xelatex?

Comment: With xelatex, use polyglossia instead. You will perhaps also have to define the languages and the corresponding fonts to use those languages. I had this in one of my latex courses. Maybe you can find the solution with the polyglossia documentation. If you can't find out how to do it, I will look into it tonight when I get hoe.

Comment: Here's some examples using `polyglossia` for Arabic and Hebrew: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354676/87678 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353999/87678

Comment: @DavidPurton xelatex + polyglossia works without my style file with hyperref, but it breaks the style file as soon as I add Arabic (makes the title not bold anymore). I'll add that minimal example to my post.

Comment: Do you have a bold face version of Amiri accessible?

Comment: I kept working on it, now that I had the stylesheet, and I got something that appears to work for at least a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

This *appears* to work for this simple example.  The stylesheet loads several packages in an order that conflicted with the packages loaded from `polyglossia`, and also used some NFSS font commands that needed to be redefined for `fontspec`.

**It must be compiled in XeLaTeX.**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[
  SizeFeatures = {
    {Size=-10,     OpticalSize=8 },
    {Size= 10,     OpticalSize=10},
    {Size= 11,     OpticalSize=11},
    {Size= 12-13,  OpticalSize=12},
    {Size= 14-18,  OpticalSize=14},
    {Size=    18-, OpticalSize=18}}
]
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Noto Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]

\usepackage[hyperref]{sty_file}
%% sty_file defines the legacy font command:
% \font\naaclhv  = phvb at 8pt 
%% This is Helvetica Bold.
\makeatletter
\newfontface\@hv{TeX Gyre Heros Bold}[Scale=1.0, OpticalSize=8]
\renewcommand\naaclhv{\fontsize{8}{8}\@hv}
\makeatother

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\title{Hebrew Arabic Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

English

\begin{Arabic}
أهلاً
\end{Arabic}

\begin{hebrew}
שלום
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

[image: Possibly-Correct Example]

### Previous

The following works for me in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

%\usepackage[hyperref]{sty_file}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase} % Should uncomment this.
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Noto Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]

\title{Hebrew Arabic Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

English

\begin{Arabic}
أهلاً
\end{Arabic}

\begin{hebrew}
שלום
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

[image: English/Arabic/Hebrew Sample]

### Previous

Thank you for posting a link to the stylesheet.  It isn’t compatible with `fontspec` in a number of ways.  Some can be easily fixed; for example, the line `\font\naaclhv  = phvb at 8pt` can be patched over by adding this afterward:

```
\makeatletter
\newfontface\@hv{TeX Gyre Heros Bold}[Scale=1.0, OpticalSize=8]
\renewcommand\naaclhv{\fontsize{8}{8}\@hv}
\makeatother
```

This makes the line, “**Confidential Review Copy. DO NOT DISTRIBUTE.**” display properly.  Similarly, you can replace `times` with TeX Gyre Termes or Times New Roman.

However, you would need to rewrite large parts of the stylesheet to get your submission to work the way you want, starting with its `\maketitle`, and you really should ask the journal itself how to proceed.

Comment: Yeah, so that displays the Arabic and Hebrew correctly for me now. The problem is, though, that it changes the English font from the one I specified in my style file (which is mandatory for my conference submission). Basically, in order to use Xelatex & Polyglossia, I need to be able to get them to not interfere with my style file, which I still can't figure out how to do.

Comment: @pjshap You didn’t include your style file, so I just commented that line out to get the example to compile. One thing you could try is to load it after `polyglossia`, which loads `fontspec`. Alternatively, you load `times` after your stylesheet, so you could do what I did and set the main font to a Times clone such as TeX Gyre Termes or Times New Roman.

Comment: @pjshap Your basic problem is that you want to use a Type 1 font for English, but OpenType fonts for Hebrew and Arabic. Your main font is set by the `times` package right now, though, so what I did should give you nearly-identical output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Bidi? you can just go: \setRL and type (or copy and paste) in Arabic and Hebrew. You can insert a Latin based language in the
middle of a RL language by the simple command \LR{latin text}. Switch RL to LR and LR to RL to reverse the process. See do-it-yourself-tex on
CTAN for some illustative examples.